# what can be optimal solution for problem?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Let there be an array: [6,9,2,4,1]

I need to find if input number have a pair or not.
 Ex. Input - 7
    Output - Yes (6+1 )

Input - 16 
   Output - No (no pair addition is 16)

I know the obvious way by running 2 loops but it have time complexity n^2 . Can someone help me with some optimized solutions ?

Programming Language : Java

What I tried : 
1) Sort array 
2) Based on input number divide it into 2 subarray (input/2). 
3) Inner loop on first array and outer loop on second

This reduces iterations.

Comment: You could do it with 1 loop, eg:
foreach(var i in array)
{
 if (array.contains( input-i))

{ //combination found
 break;
}
}

Comment: You could sort and use 2 pointers. Time Complexity is O(n log(n)) with space O(1). You can also use a HashMap which will have time complexity O(n) with space O(n). It's up to you to trade time for space or vice versa.

Comment: @Luc that's still O(n^2)

Comment: @Luc: `array.Contains` needs to lookup the data which includes looping through it...

Comment: 1. Initialize a empty hashset . 2. Run a loop and check if(hashset.contains(num - arr[i]){ return "Yes"} hashset.add(arr[i]) 3. End of loop return "No"

Answer (score 3):

Consider the same problem if your list was sorted. Then it becomes much easier to figure out whether there is a pair in the list which sums up to Input or not. Here's a high-level description of an algorithm you could use:

1. Sort your array
2. Set up two pointers `l` on the leftmost element and `r` on the rightmost
3. Move the pointers inwards one at a time, using something like the while-loop below:

As follows (pseudocode):

```
l = 0
r = length(Input) - 1
while l < r:
    if (arr[l] + arr[r] == Input) return (arr[l], arr[r])
    else if (arr[l] + arr[r] < Input) l = l+1
    else r = r-1
return NULL
```

The loop itself is linear (`O(n)`), and the sorting can be done in `O(n*log n)` time. Thus the complexity of the whole algorithm would be `O(n + n*log n) = O(n*log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

Nested for loops is O(n^2). Sorting is O(nlogn). How about this O(n) approach:

1) Create a Hashed Set of the array
2) Iterate through the array once, checking at each index i if value-arr[i] is in the set.

Example:

```
values = set(array) 
for i in array:
     if 7 - i in values:
          return i, 7-i
```